# SMART Disks Self test fail on new HD

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

I just bought a newly assembled PC with a 320GB of HD of WD. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it and did a SMART Disk test from the Disks utility in Ubuntu. It gave me following result

[image]
 I'm worried about two things here.

First, the Powered On date is 4years back. Is it an indicator that the HD probably old and used by someone else before?

Second, the overall assessment failed, showing

> Relocated Sector Count 671 sectors  FAILING

Is there anything seriously wrong? Should I replace the HD?

Comment: Heh. Sounds suspicious. Maybe someone bought it and then returned it with to the store or something with a crap harddrive. Maybe they don't check that kind of thing or something?

Comment: Ya, maybe. But its very much under warranty. Sp I will replace it.

Comment: Looks like you got scammed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is indeed a new drive, return it immediately. Reallocated sector count (especially with a huge value like that) is a sign of impending fatal failure. not all SMART stats are created equal, but bad sectors have a tendency to multiply in a small period of time. I notice that your disk is already showing more than 4 years powered on. are you sure you're looking at the right disk?

Comment: Yes, it is the only disk attached to my system. Thanks. I will return it.

Answer (score 0):

*Definitely* an old/extensively used drive:

[image: 1]